# Max / Min of date column in Pandas, columns include nan values

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe with the maximum (or minimum) date from two other date columns. But, when there is a NAN anywhere in either of those columns, the whole min/max column becomes a NAN. What gives? When using number columns this works fine... but with dates, the new column is all NANs. Here's some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan,date(2000,11,1)], 
                        [date(2000,12,1), date(2000,9,1)],
                        [date(2000,4,1),np.nan],
                        [date(2000,12,2),np.nan]], columns=['col1','col2'])

df['col3'] = df[['col1','col2']].max(axis=1)
```

I know it can be done with loc and combination of <, >, isnull and so on. But how to make it work with regular max/min functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're storing `date` objects in your columns, if you convert to `datetime` then it works as expected:

```
In[10]:
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'])
df

Out[10]: 
        col1       col2  col3
0        NaT 2000-11-01   NaN
1 2000-12-01 2000-09-01   NaN
2 2000-04-01        NaT   NaN
3 2000-12-02        NaT   NaN

In[11]:
df['col3'] = df[['col1','col2']].max(axis=1)
df

Out[11]: 
        col1       col2       col3
0        NaT 2000-11-01 2000-11-01
1 2000-12-01 2000-09-01 2000-12-01
2 2000-04-01        NaT 2000-04-01
3 2000-12-02        NaT 2000-12-02
```

If you simply did:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].max()
```

this raises a `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.date'`

The `NaN` values cause the `dtype` to be promoted to `float` so `NaN` gets returned. If you had no missing values then it would work as expected, if you have missing values then you should convert the `dtype` to `datetime` so that the missing values are converted to `NaT` so that `max` works correctly

Comment: Thanks - it indeed works with datetime. Would be nice if it could handle dates too, though ;-)

Comment: Like I said if you no `NaN` values it would work fine, even if they were `NaT` it would still fail

Comment: I meant would be nice if it handled dates WITH NaNs :)

Comment: This is more to do with incompatible types, if you had a mixture of strings and numeric then it would fail in the same manner

Comment: what a great answer. I had been using the confounding `datetime.strptime`, but pandas has an elegant in-house option that enables computation of maxima. thank you!

Comment: This answer is not working for me. Trying to find a minimum reproducible case that I can post. In meantime, `df = pd.to_datetime(df)` fails with 'ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing', but doing a loop for r in `df.columns: df[r] = pd.to_datetime(df[r]])` works (which is a bit odd). That gives me NaT and Timestamps. Great. Then `df.min(axis=0)` works but `df.min(axis=1)` returns all NaN but `df.T.min(axis=0)` returns exactly what I need.