# Pandas max date by row?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, max

The solution to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304535/4764434) unfortunately does not solve this problem. I'm using Python 3.6.2

The Dataframe, `df`:

```
                            date1                        date2
rec0    2017-05-25 14:02:23+00:00    2017-05-25 14:34:43+00:00
rec1                          NaT    2017-05-16 19:37:43+00:00
```

To reproduce the problem:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
NaT = pd.NaT

df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': [Timestamp('2017-05-25 14:02:23'), NaT],
                   'date2': [Timestamp('2017-05-25 14:34:43'), Timestamp('2017-05-16 19:37:43')]})

tz = psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)
for col in ['date1', 'date2']:
    df[col] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[col]).tz_localize(tz)
print(df.max(axis=1))
```

Both of the above columns have been converted using `pd.to_datetime()` to get the following column type: `datetime64[ns, psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)]`

Running `df.max(axis=1)` doesn't give an error but certainly provides the incorrect solution.

Output (incorrect):

```
rec0   NaN
rec1   NaN
dtype: float64
```

The fix that I have in place is to `apply` a custom function to the df as written below:

```
def get_max(x):
    test = x.dropna()
    return max(test)
df.apply(get_max,axis=1)
```

Output (correct):

```
rec0   2017-05-25 14:34:43+00:00
rec1   2017-05-16 19:37:43+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)]
```

Maybe `df.max()` doesn't deal with date objects but only looks for floats ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)). **Any idea why `df.max(axis=1)` only returns `NaN`?**

Comment: Are you sure, this seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304535/4764434?

Comment: Are all your columns datetime?

Comment: Another way to avoid the problem (which is slightly faster for large DataFrames) is: `df.stack().groupby(level=0).max()`

Comment: @JohnGalt please see @unutbu's edit to reproduce the problem. @TedPetrou yep indeed. @unutbu, I've actually had issues w/ killing the jupyter kernel using `df.stack()` on large dataframes (that might be unique to the rather deep multi-index that I was using), but as you said this solution just avoids the `pd.NaT`. Why would @unutbu's comment work for the first original row any differently though? Also of note: `max(df.iloc[0])` works for the first row as well.

Comment: What about [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38508465/6914989)?

Comment: @FabienP If you try `np.nanmax(df.iloc[1])` the [NaT](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#datetimes) value in the second row throws  `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'`, but it works fine with first row.

Comment: Then df[df.notnull()].max(axis=1) may work, slicing should be faster than using apply (can't test it right now)

Comment: @FabienP `df[df.notnull()].max(axis=1)` returns the exact same thing as `df.max(axis=1)`: the max value returned for each row is still `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it looks like there is something wrong with `pandas` and `psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone`.

If you try `df.max(axis=0)` it will work as expected, but as you indicate `df.max(axis=1)` will return a series of `NaN`.
If you do not use `psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone` as `tz`, `df.max(axis=1)` will return the expected result.

Other manipulations will fail in this case, such as `df.transpose`.

Note that if you try `df.values.max(axis=1)`, you will get the expected result. So `numpy.array` seems to be able to deal with this.
You should search in `pandas` Github issues ([like this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/7364)) and maybe consider opening a new one if you can't find a fix.

Another solution would be to drop `psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone`, but you may have some reason to use this specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas 1.0.5 with Python 3.8
I was still getting a series of Nans. Solved the issue by converting both columns to datetime and then adding skipna=True and numeric_only=False to the max() function:

```
df['1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['1'], utc=True)
df['2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['2'], utc=True) 
df['3'] = df[['1', '2']].max(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=False)
```